# Mustache templating - presenting JSON collection

Tags: javascript, mustache

I am attempting to present a JSON collection, which is retrieved asynchronously and using FireBug I can see this ultimately looks like:

```
[{"Id":"00000010"},{"Id":"00000002"},{"Id":"00000003"}]
```

This does not work, but if I declare a collection as:

```
[{ "Id": "00000004" }, { "Id": "00000005" }, { "Id": "00000006"}]
```

This works, and then using FireBug I can see this is slightly different:

```
[Object { Id="00000004"}, Object { Id="00000005"}, Object { Id="00000006"}]
```

Why does it make a difference when retrieving the data synchronously and declaring a collection? What are my options for getting this to work.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I am also using sammy.js, here is the JavaScript:

```
var app = $.sammy('div[role="main"]', function () {

    this.use('Mustache', 'html');

    this.get('#/', function (context) {
        this.load('/data')
            .then(function (response) {

                context.blah = 'blah';
                context.data = response;

                var data2 = [{ "Id": "00000004" }, { "Id": "00000005" }, { "Id": "00000006"}];
                context.data2 = data2;

                var templateUrl = '@Url.Content("~/Templates/template.html")';

                context.partial(templateUrl);
            });
    });
});

$(function () {
    app.run('#/');
});
```

Here is the template:

```
<h1>{{blah}}</h1>
<ul>
{{#data}}
<li>{{Id}}</li>
{{/data}}
</ul>
<ul>
{{#data2}}
<li>{{Id}}</li>
{{/data2}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post the actual code that does and does not work.

Comment: Yes.  You wrote: *What are my options for getting this to work?* but it's not clear what is not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured this one out!

```
context.data = response;
```

becomes

```
context.data = JSON.parse(response);
```